# For a group $G$, if $ba=a^6b$, then what is $a^ib^ja^kb^lb^{-j}a^{-i}b^{-l}a^{-k}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a group $G$, if $ba=a^6b$, then what is $a^ib^ja^kb^lb^{-j}a^{-i}b^{-l}a^{-k}$?

My attempt gives me $a^{-215i-1290k}$ which I have been told is wrong but can't see how? Does $b^ja^k$ for example, not give you $a^{6k}b^j$?

Comment: It does for $j=1$ on base of $ba^k=ba^kb^{-1}b=(bab^{-1})^kb=a^{6k}b$  but not more generally.

Comment: $ba=a^6b$ does not imply $b^j a^k = a^{6k} b^j$

Comment: Does it imply $b^ja=a^{6^{j}}b^j$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon
$$a^i b^j a^k b^l b^{-j} a^{-i} b^{-l} a^{-k}
=a^i b^j a^k b^{-j} b^l a^{-i} b^{-l} a^{-k}
=a^i (b^j a b^{-j})^k (b^la b^{-l})^{-i} a^{-k}
=a^i a^{ 6^j k} a^{-6^li} a^{-k}
$$
etc.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the jump from $(b^jab^{-j})=a^{6^{j}k}$ could you possibly explain how exactly you get this?

Comment: @harry55 How about this: $b^2 a b^{-2}=ba^6b^{-1}=(bab^{-1})^6=(a^6)^6=a^{36}$ etc.

Comment: I can't see how you go from $b^2 a b^{-2}=ba^6b^{-1}$? but the rest makes sense.. so can we say in the general case that if $ba=a^6b$, then $b^ja=a^{6^{j}}b^j$

Comment: @harry55: $b^2ab^{-2}=b(bab^{-1})b^{-1}=ba^6b^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! And finally just to confirm, is it true that if $ba=a^6b$, then $b^ja=a^{6^{j}}b^j$